# Uncompressing Zip created in Maven has smaller jar size as compared to normally created jar in target folder

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, microservices

Doing maven build with assembly plugin yields to Zip creation in which the jar size is reduced to less than 1/10th.
If I build the jar normally, then it is working fine. However, in zip creation jar size is drastically reduced.

This is leading to the following error while pushing the jar to PCF :

[image: Build failure while deploying to PCF]

[image: If you see my target folder, RestCoordinator-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar has size 41,235 kb whereas the same jar created in the Zip's target has a size of 1544 kb(when I unzip it) This leads to the above mentioned error when I push the unzipped jar to PCF]

On further comparison, it is found that the files that have source as BOOT-INF are missing as well as org/springframework/boot/loader .class files:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please post text and not images. Second please show the commands you have use. How your configuration looks like? Furthermore I don't understand the relationship between maven-assembly-plugin and jar vs. zip? Why do you use maven-assembly-plugin etc?

Comment: added @khmarbaise

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: As I said before don't use images. But as I expected you can not package a spring app with maven-assembly-plugin. The spring-boot-maven-plugin is necessary to package a spring boot application and not the maven-assembly-plugin. The question is why you started to use the maven-assembly-plugin? Simple solution use the spring-boot-maven-plugin...